# How to Import zip file from the download folder without specifiying the full name using startwith function

Tags: r

I have a zip file in my download folder with the name "Query Transaction History_20221121040329_01.xls"

This is the code I used to import the file to my machine

```
unzip(zipfile ="C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads/Query Transaction 
        History_20221121040329_42118.zip",
                    files = "Query Transaction History_20221121040329_01.xls",exdir=".")
```

I want to load this zip file without specifying the full name using the startwith function in the baser or any other process that can do the job perfectly.

this is what I want

```
 unzip(zipfile ="C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads/Query Transaction 
                History_20221121.zip",
                            files = "Query Transaction History_20221121.xls",exdir=".")
```

Comment: "using the startwith function in the baser": what does this mean?  What's the "baser"?  I know of no `startwith` function, though `starts_with` is part of `tidyselect`...

Comment: `list.files` takes a pattern argument so you can use regex string matching to identify the file and get its path

Comment: If there is only one file with the given prefix then you can specify the file using `Sys.glob("C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads/Query Transaction History_*.zip")`

Comment: @M.Viking thanks but the solution you provided is not complete
Do you wanna suggest your solution as the answer to my question rather than the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something

library(plyr)

```
my_dir<-"C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads" #specifying my foldder

zip_files <-list.files(path ="C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads",
 pattern =".*Query Transaction History_20221122.*zip",full.names = TRUE ) #list of folders that match the name of the zip file

ldply(.data = zip_files,.fun = unzip,exdir =my_dir ) #extract it to the specified folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you:

```
zipfiles <- dir("C:/Users/Guest 1/Downloads/Query Transaction",  "^History_20221121.*zip$", 
               full.names=T)
print(zipfiles)
for (zipfile in zipfiles){
  # list =T list files but not decompress them.  
  xlsfiles <- grep("Query Transaction History_20221121.*xlsx?$", 
                   unzip(zipfile = zipfile, list = T)$Name, value = T) 
  print(xlsfiles)
  unzip(zipfile = zipfile, list = xlsfiles)
}
```